# Jquery mobile shop page missing: placeholder = "Password (required)"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a shop set up in jquery mobile.
I'm missing: `placeholder = "Password (required)"`
in the below code - it's a way to insert it?

```
<input name="ctl00$bc$tbPassword"   
       type="password"   
       id="ctl00_bc_tbPassword"   
       class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
```

Comment: Sorry but what is your doubt?

Comment: I can not edit the code, but can I insert: placeholder = "Password (required)"

Comment: are you creating this input text dynamically? And is that the reason you say that you cant edit the code related to input tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have not entirely understood your problem, I believe you would be having the id of the input tag readable from javascript. Making that assumption, what you can do is, on document ready, you can add an attribute `placeholder` to your input tag.

In HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$bc$tbPassword" type="password" id="ctl00_bc_tbPassword" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
```

In JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $("#ctl00_bc_tbPassword").attr("placeholder", "Password(Required)");

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/9m6Re/1/)